# Regex to match a space character preceded by a space character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to write a regex to match the marked characters marked with a `'^'` in the following string

```
this  is    a     string
     ^   ^^^  ^^^^
```

But I'm confused about

a) how to match a character based on the character preceding it, and

b) how to match a space that is really just a space and not a tab (\t) or a new line (\n) char

I need this to work in javascript, if that makes any difference.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `' \^'` will match a substring like `" ^"`

Comment: OP means the characters marked in the question by a `^` (so the spaces)

Comment: do you try to remove duplicate spaces?

Comment: In javascript, there is no lookbehinds. So you'll need to match that space and put the others in a matching group (or vice versa depending on your goals) : `space(space+)` -> replace space with a literal space 0x20

Comment: `replace(/\s+/g,' ')`?

Comment: @putvande: you forget the b) requirement.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, no my goal is to replace the spaces with `&nbsp`'s (edited the post to reflect this)

Comment: Why? You could just use `white-space: pre;` on the element containing the text (which is far easier).

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm very intrigued. Could you elaborate a little a bit? Is it that adding that css property to a div makes it so that successive white spaces in html aren't flattened into a single white space?

Comment: [`white-space: pre`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Bnvk4/) preserves the white-space (prevents it being collapsed down to a single space) in an element, as it was entered into the HTML.

Comment: @DavidThomas Incredible. Yes that's what I want. Now I feel bad about having wasted everyone's time with this question...

Comment: @DavidThomas: nobody has wasted his time here.

Comment: @Casimir: I never suggested they had. I simply felt the wrong problem was being asked and solved; hence my suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the lack of lookbehinds, the best you can do is find the overall match using this, and then just use capture group `1`:

```
/(?: )( +)/g
```

Or, in whatever code uses the match information, just assume that the first character is a space, and use this regex:

```
/ +/g
```

Comment: After trying these out, they both seem to match the first space as well as the subsequent spaces. e.g. `"a  b".replace(/(?: )( +)/g, "-")` evaluates to `"a-b"`, while I'd expect it to evaluate to `"a -b"`. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding this though?

Comment: Well, the SO comment formatting makes it very difficult to illustrate this, but that string that I'm calling replace on is supposed to read `"a[space][space][space]b"` instead of "ab"

Comment: Yes, that's why I specifically mentioned you'd have to use capture group 1, or assume that the first character should be ignored.

Comment: (JavaScript does not have lookbehinds)

Comment: Ah, okay. I guess I'm not familiar with the concept of capture groups so I glazed over that part. Could you elaborate a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `String.replace( regexp , replaceWith )`

and use the RegExp `/([ ]+)/g`

This will replace any space preceeded with any number of spaces with just a space

`var string = "I  have   multiple    spaces     .";`

Then, you would use a custom function to replace it with.

```
var marked = string.replace(/([ ]+)/g, function( p1 ){
    return " " + p1.slice(0,-1).replace(/[ ]/g, '&nbsp;');
});
```

Here is a fiddle with a working example http://jsfiddle.net/h5C7p/

Comment: @HamZa Fixed based on your comment

Comment: I updated it to replace the preceeding spaces with `&nbsp;`'s

Comment: This really bothered me, not working, I had to make it work. What I ended up doing was splicing the first space and add it back after replacing all spaces with `&nbsp;`